# How to add new page in VS 2010 with tfs

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am completely new to TFS 2010 and am trying to use it for basic source control. I have successfully added an exsting project, however I cannot figure out how to add a basic new .aspx file. I know I am missing something completely obvious here.

Is there another product I should consider altogether? My needs are very basic and TFS seems to be complicated for what I am doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question: if you think TFS is too complicated, then google an alternative and try it.  Version control is not simple, though, and you won't necessarily make it any easier by changing products.

For your first question: add the aspx file to your project exactly as you normally would.  If you do this in Visual Studio then the file will be added to your "Pending Changes" list in TFS automatically, and all you need to do is check in.

Comment: The adding is the problem. The normal right click  menu in solution explorer does not have an "add item" choice. Hold on - I just closed the project and re-opened it and it is back. So problem solved - but why was it missing in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on .soln in Source Control Explorer-->"Get Latest"
2. Open the .soln
3. In solution explorer, right click on your project or a folder -->"Add"
4. Right click on the new file once you've created it and "Check in"